# Only Inkscape (and GitHub) render SVG correctly

Tags: inkscape, svg

I am using Inkscape 0.92.1 (4.20170510bzr15686.fc26) on Fedora 26.

To verify the issue, I also exported the SVG in Inkscape, but **both files** are rendered incorectly on my system.

Original SVG: https://cdn.rawgit.com/rugk/streetcomplete-quest-svgs/7098e53fbc2d7c4ab737c2d32576b67b771d15f5/inkscape/StreetComplete_quest_crossing.svg
Optimized SVG: https://cdn.rawgit.com/rugk/streetcomplete-quest-svgs/7098e53fbc2d7c4ab737c2d32576b67b771d15f5/optimized/StreetComplete_quest_crossing.svg

(Maybe it works in the browser, try saving the files and opening them in another way, then.)

#### How it should look

This is how it looks:

- on GitHub (even on my system; they use some custom SVG renderer or so)
- in Inkscape on my system itself (also the preview in the opening/saving dialog looks correct)

[image: good svg]

#### How it looks

Opening the plain SVG file in

- [in BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/81922ca8f06cbe5aff8b9928379f572dd2a17a16) for Windows and MacOS and other systems
- nautilus
- Eye of GNOME and other picture viewers
- Firefox 55
- and GIMP (2.8.22)

…they however always look distorted:
[image: distorted icon]

I see all zebra icons being affected here, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/rugk/streetcomplete-quest-svgs/blob/master/optimized/StreetComplete_quest_tactilepavingcrossing.svg) ([original](https://github.com/rugk/streetcomplete-quest-svgs/blob/master/inkscape/StreetComplete_quest_tactilepavingcrossing.svg)) is also distorted:
[image: distorted 2]

So what (or where) is the issue, i.e. who is responsible? Is it a bug in Inkscape or in the rendering library used on my system or is it the SVG's fault?

**Edit:** Now I even see the correct ones in the version without the bug fix when opening the files with Firefox. Still reproducible with other offline software, however.

Comment: The author of the SVGs actually showed me a workaround. Using "Stroke to path". This helps as a workaround to fix the display issue, but this still does not help me to find the original/source issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have tried these in Chrome 60.0.3112.113,  Firefox 55.0.3, and Inkscape  0.92.1, on Windows 7, and both these links render  identically in all programs. Sorry I don't use IE, or MS Edge.

Comment: I am sorry, I think this is because I applies [the workaround described](https://github.com/rugk/streetcomplete-quest-svgs/commit/2d0d369a865886de2fa01abc4c6a0d9248aa38e8). I'll change the links to static ones pointing to the faulty SVGs. Also note that on GItHub they are **always** rendered correctly.

Comment: Both (original and optimized) display OK (and identically) in Chromium, FF55, and Inkscape. Both look distorted in Okular, Gwenview, and Gimp. It could be a bug in some SVG rendering library...

Answer (score 3):

I tried to open your SVG in my software [Photopea.com](//www.Photopea.com) and it looks correct.

The problem is, that you use [paint-order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/paint-order) property in your SVG. This property was defined in SVG2 and probably is not yet supported in GIMP.

You have `paint-order: stroke fill markers;` which says, that stroke should be painted under the fill. By default, stroke is always painted on top of the fill.

[Smaller example](https://jsfiddle.net/hne0kyLg/1/) – try deleting the `paint-order` property.

So the problem is not in your file, but in GIMP and other software, which does not support the paint-order property yet. You can report it to authors as a bug. In web browsers, everything should look fine.

Comment: Your example file looks alright: https://pageshot.net/VXVOXGC4dKCf0q6K/jsfiddle.net